# Add open $wf.$ to consistent first order system

Tags: logic

I've trying to solve this for a while.

**Problem**

Let $L$ be a first order language with the predicate symbol $p$. Let S be the extension obtained by adding to $K_L$ the open $wf. p(x, y)$. Is S consistent?

**Definitions**

In my bibliography there is not definition of openness, but closeness. It is: A $wf. A$ of $L$ is said to be closed if no variable occurs free in $A$.

$K$ is a consistent first order system.

The book I'm using is: *Logic for mathematicians*, Hamilton.

**My thoughts**

Well, I think that **it is** consistent because a model can be created for $S$.

**My question**

In reality, what it is really puzzling me is the **open** word. What is the difference of creating an extension by adding an **open** or a **closed** $wf.$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget details of notation Hamilton uses, though I once (but only once!) used it as text. Adding $p(x,y)$ should be harmless. Take the previous model, and interpret $p$ by saying $p(a,b)$ holds for all $a$, $b$ in the model.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thank you very much for your comment. I've modified the post a bit in order to make my question cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual convention is that if we put the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ is a system of axioms, that is equivalent to using $\forall x\forall y\varphi(x,y)$. Just shorter, saves trees.

Recall for example that one of the axioms used in the definition of group is $x(yz)=(xy)z$. There is implicit universal quantification of the three variable symbols.